# cgpav not scanning in CommuniGate Pro

Tags: email-server, anti-virus, debian-squeeze

I have setup cgpav and cgpsa.  Spamassassin works fine - the cgpav filter seems to run, cgpro log files just show OK when it receives an email with a known virus (eicar test virus), however, if run cgpav from the command prompt, the actual filter, run as root, it shows the addfilter, if I manually run the scanner, it finds the virus as well.  However, it seems not to find anything when cgpro runs the filter.  I had it setup so it scans everything.

Has anyone else got this issue because I really would love to have this finally up and running.